# Micro Front End Routing : Angular Router in Web Component/angular element

Tags: angular, routes, web-component, angular-elements, micro-frontend

I am creating an UI application using **micro front end** architecture. I have three application :
1. **micro-app-a** (written in angular)
2. **micro-app-b** (written in angular)
3. **shell application** (written in angular)

My **micro-app-a** has its own angular router to manage routing and similarly **micro-app-b** also has its own angular router which are working as expected individually but i am not able to manage routing when i clubbing these two micro apps  as a **web component (@angular/element)** into a single shell application . i am not getting how to manage routing . Please help me here who ever has the knowledge.:)

Comment: Were you able to find any solution for this. One question how you are deploying you prod build files. As far as I understand angular elements needs to run on some port. How are you doing that ..?

Comment: We are also looking into a solution for this. Found this example online https://github.com/manfredsteyer/angular-microfrontend/blob/master/src/app/shell/shell.service.ts

And am looking into it now, but I'm not sure it's the way

Comment: @Amit is there any update on this? Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: @Atul is there any update on this? Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: Maybe this article (https://medium.com/@timon.grassl/how-to-use-routing-in-angular-web-components-c6a76449cdb) will help you out with your problem